# Evitar registros duplicados jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estoy intentando evitar los registros duplicados, pero no consigo hacerme con ello.

```
data.productos.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.sub_cat == null){
      var cate = '<span class="catProd">'+ item.categoria.name +' / '+ item.etiqueta.name +'</span>';
      var enlace = '/product/'+item.categoria.slug+'/'+item.etiqueta.slug+'/'+item.slug+'';
    }else{
      var cate = '<span class="catProd">'+ item.categoria.name +' / '+ item.sub_cat.name +' / '+ item.etiqueta.name +'</span>';
      var enlace = '/productos/'+item.categoria.slug+'/'+ item.sub_cat.slug +'/'+item.etiqueta.slug+'/'+item.slug+'';
    }
    $('.barra_busqueda').append('<a href="'+ enlace +'" class="b_search">\
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">\
         <span class="nameProd">'+ item.name +'</span>\
         '+ cate +'\
      </div>\
    </a>');                         
});
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
{productos: Array(2)}
  productos
  : 
  Array(2)
  0
  : 
   {id: 20, 
    referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219114', 
    busquedaCategoria: 'busquedas', 
    category_id: 2, 
    subcategory_id: 13, 
    …
   }
  1
  : 
   {id: 21, 
    referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219114', 
    busquedaCategoria: 'busquedas', 
    category_id: 1, 
    subcategory_id: 15, 
    …
   }
  length
```

Estoy intentando con esto:

```
$.unique(item);
 function unique(array){
  return array.filter(function(el,index,item){
  return index == item.indexOf(el);
 });
}
```

Pero me devuelve la consola:

```
a.sort is not a function
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si el campo `referenciaLimpia` son iguales no se imprima en el append. ¿Eso es posible?

Comment: No se entiende, dices `Lo que quiero hacer es que si el campo referenciaLimpia son iguales no se imprima en el append` esto lo entiendo como si existe datos repetidos no se imprima NINGUNO, favor confirmar y si no es así...cual se imprime el primero? el último? .- Por último y muy importante es que formatees correctamente el array de entrada para facilitar la respuesta

Comment: En el caso de que este repetido el registro, me da igual cual saque, siempre y cuando si hay 4 solo saque uno. @Yussef es como un `distinct` en php pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

En javascript existen 2 elementos que se llaman map

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) que es una colección tipo diccionarios, donde se guardan id unicas
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) función de los array que sirve para convertir el array original en otro.

*(Uno comienza con mayúsculas y el otro no)*

Para encontrar los distintos haremos uso de los 2. con `map` convertiremos el array original en un array [clave,valor], donde clave es el elemento diferenciador es decir `referenciaLimpia`, este array se los pasaremos a `new Map` el cual filtrará los distintos por nosotros

```
const distintos = new Map(arr.map(a=>[a.referenciaLimpia,a]));
```

Aquí un ejemplo completo:

```js
const arr = [{id: 20, referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219114'}, {id: 20, referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219114'}, {id: 21, referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219115'}, {id: 22, referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219112'}, {id: 22, referenciaLimpia: 'sh00219112'}];

const distintos = new Map(arr.map(a=>[a.referenciaLimpia,a]));

//distintos en un Map y se puede iterar
for(let item of distintos){
   console.log(item);
}

//tambien lo podemos convertir en array
const array_distintos = [...distintos].map(([clave,valor])=>valor);
console.log(array_distintos);
```